# Debugging font shape undefined in TeXShop

Tags: fonts, formatting, mac, debugging

I am a LaTeX newbie on a Mac running OS X Mavericks, TexShop 3.26 and MacTeX-2013.  I am writing a document and I keep getting the following warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/phvr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 186.
```

I understand that this warning is saying helvetica (Karl Berry names), medium, normal lacks a particular shape so computer modern is being used as a fallback.  My problem is that I cannot determine which shape this is.  The input line number appears to correspond to a processed intermediate of my document.  How does one go about tracking an issue like this down?  I'd like to be able to inspect the offending symbol so I can make sure to pay attention to it in the typeset document.

Comment: What's on line 186 of your `.tex` file?

Comment: Line 186 is just `\begin{abstract}`, which is why I think the line number must be referring to some intermediate representation.

Comment: Hmm. Honestly the best way to track down the offending issue might be the process of trying to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). What happens if you make a new document with the same preamble and the contents from `\begin{abstract}` to `\end{abstract}`? Can you reproduce the problem? Then, try narrowing things down from there, taking things out until you figure out what is causing it.

Comment: You are trying to use a font which is not defined for use with LaTeX on your system. I am guessing you do not actually have that font installed for use with LaTeX. It is impossible to suggest anything useful without a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem, however. How are you specifying fonts? Are you using `pdflatex`, `latex` or something else? Is this TeX Live? Normally, TeX would substitute for that font with an available look-alike but it depends on how you are specifying it etc.

Comment: `phvr` is an odd family name. It is naturally possible that some private font package uses it, but perhaps it is simply a typo and you mean `phv`.

Comment: I am using `pdflatex` and this is the TeX Live distribution. I have `phvr` at `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/helvetic/phvr.tfm`. I should mention that I am using the PNAS template (<http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml>), which suggests using the `phvr` font in the style file (`PNAStwoF.sty`).

Comment: I made a MWE that just declared the document class and the abstract environment and got the same warning.  I guess the PNAS template is causing this warning and not a particular symbol that I entered.

Comment: @weitzner That link gets me a page not found error. Why don't you *post* your MWE? The fact that you have `phvr.tfm` does *not* mean that you have the relevant font installed. The .tfm is not enough alone and, in any case, that would not show you what you needed to specify in order to use the font with LaTeX, even if it were. (I have that file, too, but I don't have Adobe's Helvetica installed for all that.) It is really difficult to help without the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "shape" is `T1/phvr/m/n` that is the internal latex font name.

It doesn't refer to a particular symbol, you say "inspect the offending symbol" but there need be no symbol in the document using this font. The warning is given when LaTeX tries to switch to the font, even if nothing is actually typeset in that font. For example if you don't have a bold font then you would get a similar warning from `\textbf{}` even though the argument is empty and no bold characters are used.  As Ulrike commented the `phvr` looks like a typo for `phv` (Helvetica).

Comment: Ah ok.  The default font in this section is bold, so that would likely explain why it wasn't obviously using the wrong font in the section.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @weitzner Sorry? Your comment doesn't make sense. That's just an analogy i.e. here's another way of triggering the same kind of error. It is not trying to switch to bold in your case. It is looking for a font in upright shape, mediumn weight of family `phvr` in T1 encoding. And it is not finding it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - the default font in the abstract environment is bold (per the PNAS template), so the `T1/phvr/m/n` font is never actually being used.  I can trigger the warning by just starting the environment with `\begin{abstract}`